# IntelliJ: Re-format existing code with additional rules

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Is there a way to apply new formatting rules for existing code in IntelliJ like how Eclipse does upon saving files?

For example in Eclipse, the "on save actions" can be configured with additional settings like:

1. Insert `final` keyword wherever applicable (method arguments, object fields etc.)
2. Wrap single line control statements with braces.
3. Remove unused variables/private methods.

These would work for both new and existing code upon saving the file.

Although we can configure IntelliJ to follow these rules for new code, is there a way to apply these rules for existing code as well? 
Currently I just see basic re-formatting such as indentation, placement of braces and imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that all formating rules are set as desired in the standard IntelliJ rules.

Then open the Project Tool Window (`View | Tool Windows | Project` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) and select a source package. You can then reformat all included source files at once (`Code | Reformat Code` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

To **insert missing final** in all your files, make sure that the inspection `Field may be final` (see settings) is activated. Select a non-final variable, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose `Make final` | `Run on...` Choose `Whole project` as inspection scope. Another method is to `Analyze | Inspect Code...` and then run that inspection on your whole project.

*BTW: I have switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ, too. In retrospect these additional "on save" rules only lead to extra-work when synchronizing with my team.*

Comment: Thanks, but apart from optimizing imports and re-arranging entries, it doesn't apply other rules (such as adding `final` to method parameters) which Eclipse does on saving.

Comment: true; this depends on the action; I have updated my answer for "insert missing final". "Remove unused..." can be done that way, too. The "wrap with braces" is covered by formatting rules.